# Flutter: How to store Numbers as String Sqflite?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, sqflite

When I store "00012" as `String` in sqflite its automatically converted to integer and the zeros are removed (only getting 12 as `int` data type).

**Sample code:**

Add permissions to `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also grant storage permissions manually on device to create database.

```
 import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

Future<Database> _getDatabase() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String path = join(directory.path, "MyDataBase");
  Database database = await openDatabase(
    path,
    version: 1,
    onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE test (col1 STRING PRIMARY KEY, col2 STRING)',
      );
    },
  );
  return database;
}

Database db;

Future<void> main() async {
  db = await _getDatabase();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Test",
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Future<dynamic> valueFromDb;

  Future<int> _saveToDB(String id, String text) async {
    final data = await _loadFromDB(id);
    if (data == null)
      return db.insert(
        "test",
        {
          "col1": id,
          "col2": text,
        },
      );
    return 0;
  }

  Future<dynamic> _loadFromDB(String id) async {
    final results = await db.query(
      "test",
      where: "col1 = ?",
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
    if (results?.isNotEmpty == true) return results.first["col2"];
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Save 00012 as String to DB"),
              onPressed: () => _saveToDB("MyID", "000012"),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Load Value"),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  valueFromDb = _loadFromDB("MyID");
                });
              },
            ),
            FutureBuilder(
              future: valueFromDb,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                else
                  return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Value from DB: ${snapshot.data?.toString() ?? ""}",
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Data Type: ${snapshot.data?.runtimeType ?? ""}",
                      )
                    ],
                  );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
'CREATE TABLE test (col1 STRING PRIMARY KEY, col2 STRING)'
```

To

```
'CREATE TABLE test (col1 TEXT PRIMARY KEY, col2 TEXT)'
```

Read [rule number 3 and 5](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) about affinity,

```
If the STRING or BLOB looks like a real number (if it has a decimal point or an 
exponent) or if the value is outside the range that can be represented 
as a 64-bit signed integer, then it converts to REAL
```

REAL is like a double in this case. STRING is not really a type in SQLite (check the table in 3.1.1) so it will consider it as a BLOB and try to specify an affinity based on the value stored. Telling to use one of the TEXT affinity will force it to treat it as text (VARCHAR, CHARACTER, etc), that is, a String in dart